# Can I clear cache only for particular domain / URL?

Tags: caching, subsites

I'm using domain module with several domains. With drush you can clear cache using cc command. I have only one database for all domains.

I'm wondering can I clear cache using only specific domain (with -l option) if I'm using same DB for all domains?

e.g: `$ drush -l http://www.example.com cc all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just core this is not possible. If you where to write your own cache backend then what you're asking for could be done. An example of a custom cache backend is http://drupal.org/project/adbc